# Turtlebot on mac OSX

Tags: rosdep, catkin, ros-hydro, turtlebot, mac

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've being trying to get ROS + turtlebot (Hydro) installed on my mac (running osx 10.10).
ROS installed happily.
However I am running into a few issues with compiling the turtlebot specific packages from source (http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/hydro/Installation).

When I run:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y
```

I get the following errors:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
kobuki_ftdi: No definition of [ftdi-eeprom] for OS [osx]
kobuki_qtestsuite: No definition of [pyqt4-dev-tools] for OS [osx]
```

As expected, continuing on with catkin-make doesn't work out too well.

How would I go about solving/getting arounds this? (I don't mind if its not a full blown answer, would at least like to be pointed in the right direction)

Also, just for reference, a somewhat similar question was asked quite a while back without that much success:
http://answers.ros.org/question/89831/install-turtelbot-simulator-on-mac-os/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198888/turtlebot-on-mac-osx/) by [genericsoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/20987/genericsoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2014-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message you're getting from rosdep indicates that it can't find two packages that it depends on: `ftdi-eeprom` and `pyqt4-dev-tools`. Both of these packages have pages on the ubuntu package site: [ftdi-eeprom](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ftdi-eeprom) and [pyqt4-dev-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python/pyqt4-dev-tools), which should give you links back to the original package website and sources.

You'll need to figure out if these packages are available through homebrew or pip; if they are, you can simply install them and add the appropriate rosdep keys, as the previous answer suggests. (See [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/196076/building-indigo-on-1410/) for instructions on how to set up local rosdep keys so that you can test them before submitting them to [rosdistro](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml))

If you can't find these packages in homebrew or pip, you'll have to look into building and installing them from source on OSX. If you can get them manually installed, rosdep probably won't be able to detect that they're installed, but you should still be able to run catkin_make and build the turtlebot packages against them.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-12-04**:
For local testing you can also use the `--skip-key` to rosdep if you are confident that the dependency has been resolved.

**Comment by [genericsoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/20987/genericsoup/) on 2014-12-06**:
Thanks for the pointers guys, will have a go at this over the coming days.